# c# Recursive Function for Object with Self child object using XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

I have an object called **folder** that has a child object of itself.

```
public class Folder(){
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public List<Document> Documents { get; set; }
  public List<Folder> Folders { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have an **xml** that i need to deserialize into this object.

**sample:**

```
<folder name="folder1">
      <folder name="childfolder1">
        <folder name="childfolder1-1">
          <folder name="childfolder1-1-1">
            ......
          </folder>
      <document name="document1-1-1"/>
    </folder>
    <document name="document1-1"/>
  </folder>
  <folder name="childfolder2">
    <folder name="childfolder2-1">
      <folder name="childfolder2-1-1">
        ......
      </folder>
      <document name="document2-1-1"/>
    </folder>
  </folder>
  <document name="document1"/>
</folder>
```

I need help in writing a logic that can convert the xml into the object using **XmlSerializer**.

Any help will be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What have you got so far? What is the problem? SO is not a coding service...

Comment: Hi sorry for not posting the code. I already figured out a way to do it. I'll edit my question and post my answer.